# MySQL GROUP BY text type field

Tags: mysql, text, group-by

Does GROUP BY work on text type field?
For example, I have a text type column named as `story`

Can I find the count of similar stories like this

select story, count(*) from mytable group by 1;

Will GROUP BY evaluate on the basis of complete texts in the story column or just a few first characters?

Comment: Try it out?...Of what datatype exactly is story?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

GROUP BY is an aggregator and hence it is compulsory to use an aggregate function like SUM, COUNT, AVG, etc. with GROUP BY.

Regarding your question, Yes GROUP BY can be used with varchar or string columns. And what you are trying to achieve can be better achieved with using the query:

`select story, count(*) from mytable group by story;`